# ADB in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, adb

I'm learning to use Android Studio. I've downloaded Android Studio Canary 4.1 from developer.android.com. When I started to run a template, I got this error (shown in pictures below). 
I hope someone can help me with this.

[image]

And this was shown in Help | Show log

```
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 m 0 s 845 ms) 
2020-04-23 07:36:09,826 [ 240277]   INFO - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - Updating model took 0.04s 
2020-04-23 07:36:09,882 [ 240333]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-04-23 07:36:10,121 [ 240572]   WARN - openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil - LocalFileSystem failed to extract root path '' from '//help.gradle.org' (original '//help.gradle.org') 
2020-04-23 07:36:10,214 [ 240665]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 47 ms 
2020-04-23 07:36:10,229 [ 240680]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.GradleScriptInputsWatcher$Storage 
2020-04-23 07:36:10,238 [ 240689]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.configuration.utils.ScriptClassRootsStorage 
2020-04-23 07:36:10,261 [ 240712]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=My Application, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication) XDebuggerManager took 12 ms 
2020-04-23 07:36:10,384 [ 240835]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-04-23 07:36:11,391 [ 241842]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-04-23 07:36:11,892 [ 242343]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-04-23 07:36:12,392 [ 242843]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-04-23 07:36:12,899 [ 243350]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2020-04-23 07:36:13,403 [ 243854]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found
```

Comment: can you provide more context to what "DummyModel" is in your project? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what "DummyModel" is in my project, this is a template "Basic Activity" in Android studio and I haven't fixed anything . Thank you

Comment: Well i would suggest you to uninstall Canary version as its bleeding edge technology . Rather install stable version:  https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5YSagav96AIVxkXVCh1T3ghnEAAYASAAEgIk6_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to install a stable version. It may help

Comment: It also says no ADB found. You might not have Android Debug Bridge installed. It comes shipped with android SDK. try reinstalling the android SDK or go in SDK manager and make sure ADB is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you shout sync successfully , in case you can`t sync successfully?

*Follow this steps,*

1. Download latest version of `gradle`  .
2. [gradle download link](https://gradle.org/releases/)
3. After downloading it extract new folder.
4. Then open android studio. Go to **file->settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle**.
5. Then choose **Use local gradle distribution** and in the **Gradle home** give path of the folder where we have extracted file.
6. Finally restart your android studio.

Otherwise it will be occur from **offline work** in **Global Gradle Settings** , if its checked please **UnCheck** it. Have a nice day.